# Can't open ssl localhost

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-10, localhost, hosts

I'm studying ASP and trying to run an example application with the following configuration from **launchSettings.json** on Windows 10 and Kestrel Web Server:

```
"RazorPagesMovie": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Application is available at:

- http://localhost:5000
- http://127.0.0.1:5000
- https://127.0.0.1:5001

Problem is that application isn't available at **https://localhost:5001**

- When I faced this I thought that problem is in a certificate, but later I found out that I can open https://127.0.0.1:5001
- When I try to open https://localhost:5001 I see the next page in Google Chrome:
  [image]
- My hosts:

  ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost       
   ::1             localhost
  ```

I understand that problem is in my OS (I tried running it on another PC and all was OK) but I want to understand what I can do to solve such problems on Windows. I mean what tools I can use, what command-line utilities might be useful to understand what is wrong.

Comment: *ANY* URL, either http or https, needs a "web server".  For example, "Visual Studio > debug" starts an instance of "IIS Express".  Q: What is *your* web server?  Or are you just using the MSVS debugger?  Q: Exactly what file is the "configuration" you showed us?  It matters.  Q: Does `https://127.0.0.1:5001` (vs. `https://localhost:5001`) work?  Does it display your web page?  I wasn't clear from your description...

Comment: 1) I'm talking about launchSettings.json configuration file.
2) As I understand `"commandName": "Project"` leads to using Kestrel Web Server
3) 
`http://localhost:5000` - opens;
`https://localhost:5001` - doesn't open;
`http://127.0.0.1:5000` - opens;
`https://127.0.0.1:5001` - opens

Comment: 1) What is the URL for the next page? Don't ever miss such simple but critical details when troubleshooting. 2) Keep Developer Tools open so that you can always monitor what requests/responses are there on the wire.

Comment: @LexLi I mean `https://localhost:5001`. I've updated the problem description.

Comment: @Vadim - When I run an ASP.Net Core/Razor app from my MSVS 2019, "debug" button and "Project > Properties > Debug" both say "IIS Express". Q: are you running your app from the MSVS IDE, did you install/configure your own web browser, or "something else"?  The key issue seems to be that your client (the browser) isn't connecting to your web server at `https://localhost:5001`. SUGGESTION:  Follow Lex Li's advice:  "Keep Developer Tools open so that you can always monitor what requests/responses are there on the wire".  Please keep us posted what you learn!